# error while fetching from DynamoDB using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using below code to read from dyanoDB

```
 import boto3
 session = boto3.Session(
           aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

 dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb')
 table = dynamodb.Table('Employee')

 resp = table.get_item(Key={"Empid": 551554297})
```

This user has AWSAdmin access,DynamoDBfull Access and DyanamoDBread Access
But still i am getting below errror while running the code

```
 botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) 
 when calling the GetItem operation: User: 
 arn:aws:iam::944198216610:user/cduser is not authorized to perform: 
 dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east- 
 1:944198216610:table/Employee
```

Can someone help me figure out what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just some ideas: does it have to do with the region or the specific table? Have you checked your aws config and credentials files in case those are overriding? Is there another error, but you don't have permissions to see the error so you get a permissions error instead?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs

Comment: Side-note: It is recommended that you _never_ put credentials inside your code, in case it leaks out (eg gets stored in a repository). Instead, store your credentials locally by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command.

Comment: @John Point Noted.

Comment: The symptoms suggest that your credentials are valid but the associated permissions are insufficient. You should double-check the permissions for IAM user `cduser`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found with docker containers, even if you set your access and secret keys as environment variables during the build, you have to still explicitly declare region, key_id and access_key in your script:  *ex. boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=<>, aws_access_key_id=<>, aws_secret_access_key=<>)* .

An alternative to having those set in plain text of your script is to store them in ~/.aws/config and ~/.aws/credentials or, even better, mounted as a secret.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while using the default role of the lambda function.
Adding extra dynamodb statement to policy solved the problem in my case.

```
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
          "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
          "dynamodb:GetItem",
          "dynamodb:ListTables",
          "dynamodb:Query",
          "dynamodb:Scan"
      ],
      "Resource": [<dynamodb table ARN>]
    }
```

Comment: Please don't format code as a runnable code-snippet **unless it is a runnable code snippet**. Yours is *not* a runnable code snippet - just use a normal code block.